# Error executing connecting to database and executing database query

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a log in for a website. index.php file controls what is displayed by checking the user details. It display a message if user is logged in else the login form. I have included the files connect.php and core.php. When I open index.php I get the following error. The variable con is already defined but it shows it is undefined please help me to find the mistake Thanks in advance.

**Error:**

```
Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\core.php on line 33

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\core.php on line 33

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\core.php on line 34
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/connect.php' ;
require_once 'includes/core.php' ;

if(logged_in())
{
    echo "You are logged in" ;
}
else
{
?>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Password <a href="resetpass.php">Forgot Password?</a></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="email" name="sin_email" placeholder="Email" name="email"></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="sin_pass" placeholder="Password" name="pass"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Log In"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

**includes/core.php**

```
<?php
//Start output buffer.Stores all the output of the server into a stack
ob_start() ;
//Start a session
session_start() ;
//Get the name of current file
$current_file=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ;
//Get the referrer to this page if any
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
{
    $http_referrer=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ;
}

function logged_in()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_token'],$_SESSION['user_name'],$_SESSION['user_id']) 
    && !empty($_SESSION['login_token']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_name']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
    {
        //Store session variable to local variables
        $user_name=$_SESSION['user_name'] ;
        $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'] ;
        $http_agent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ;
        $ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ;

        //Recreating the token string
        $token_string=$user_name.$user_id.$http_agent.$ip_address ;

        //Obtaining the md5 value for the token_string
        $obtained_login_token=md5($token_string) ;

        //Fetching previous token_string stored in the database
        $token_query="SELECT * FROM securelogin WHERE user_id='$user_id' ;" ;
        $token_result=mysqli_query($con,$token_query) ;
        $token_info=mysqli_fetch_assoc($token_result) ;
        $stored_login_token=$token_info['login_string'] ;

        if($stored_login_token===$obtained_login_token)
        {
            return true ;
        }
        else
        {
            return false ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false ;
    }
}
?>
```

**includes/connect.php**

```
<?php
$host_name="localhost" ;
$user_name="root" ;
$password="" ;
$db_name="futsided" ;

$con=mysqli_connect($host_name,$user_name,$password,$db_name)
or
die("Cannot connect to our server :(<br/>Please try again later or contact <a href=\"/report.html\">Administrator</a>") ;
?>
```

Comment: It says `$con` is not defined and none of the code you've shown defines it, so I'm going to bet on PHP being right and you being wrong.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: try googling the item atleast once before putting it

Comment: show `connect.php` code ?

Comment: You are using $con on line 33 without defining it before, you need to use a mysqli_connect and assoc that to a var maybe

Comment: Edit: to use $con inside logged_in function you need to pass it inside the function as a parameter on the call of the function. Otherwise you can think about including connect inside the function or use some global var (if supported)

Comment: How stupid am I. Thank you so much @MarcoMura .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to transfer the variable $con to the function logged_in ($con is not globally defined):

In index.php change

```
if(logged_in())
```

to

```
if(logged_in($con))
```

In includes/core.php change

```
function logged_in()
```

to

```
function logged_in($con)
```